# Search Firebase Database for specific key/value pair of all Users

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am attempting to search my Firebase database for all values of my IDNumber key/value pair that match the numbers I type in my edit Text (editTextValue). But what ends up happening is that my code only searches against the first users IDNumber key/value pair only.

How do I search the IDNumbers of each user in my database for a match?
The DatabaseReference I put in my onClick method is as follows:

```
    mFirebaseDatabase.child("users").orderByChild("IDNumber").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {

            User userRef = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class) ;



            if (editTextValue.equals(userRef.IDNumber)) {
                textView.setText(R.string.user_notified) ;
            } else {
                textView.setText(R.string.IDNumber_not_found) ;
            }

        }
```

My User class is as follows if needed too:

```
public class User {
public String name ;
public String IDNumber ;


public User() {
}

public User(String name, String IDNumber) {
    this.name = name ;
    this.IDNumber = IDNumber ;
}

public String getName() {
    return name ;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: How would u say that, as if another id matches, the editText will still give the same output.

Comment: To check the results just Log all the values.

Comment: can you post your database structure?

Comment: ****-df5dd
app_title: 
"****"
users
-LhJeqbrobPmmURtM
licensePlateNumber: 
"i3t4Uxi48"
name: 
"Drius Shquille"
-LLxp7VvfuJf05NAe
licensePlateNumber: 
"6iy37Uoi"
name: 
"Jonnie"
-LI12yGH_Jw3Unz0F
licensePlateNumber: 
"ababcd3"
name: 
"Torq"     Here's a copy and paste of my structure @GastónSaillén

Answer (score 0):

Add a getter in your pojo

```
public String getIDNumber() {
    return IDNumber ;
}
```

Change your listener

```
   mFirebaseDatabase.child("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        //We iterate inside the parent node in order to get all childrens
        for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                //Get IDNumber from everybody
                User userRef = snapshot.getValue(User.class) ;
                String userIDNumber = userRef.getIDNumber();
                Log.e("IDNumbers: " , "" + userIDNumber);

           }


      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
      }

 });
```

You dont need your constructor, instead you can use the empty one

delete this one

```
public User(String name, String IDNumber) {
    this.name = name ;
    this.IDNumber = IDNumber ;
}
```

use just this one

```
public User() {
}
```

Comment: It's still taking the last name/value pair entered into the database. Should I take the reference out of the onClick method and into the onCreate method with a few alterations? @Gaston